# Multivariate regression libraries in fortran

Tags: fortran, regression, interpolation, multivariate-testing

I find several multivariate regression and curve fitting libraries developed in (a) C/C++ eg. [Dlib](http://dlib.net), [Dakota](https://dakota.sandia.gov), (b) python has eg.[scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).

For fortran I found [INTERP](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/interp/interp.html) but I want to know if there are actively developed and maintained multivariate regression libraries in fortran.

NOTE: Not libraries which have fortran APIs but those written in fortran

Comment: Just write a fortran interface and link the c code into a library and then you can use anywhere you want..
(You may need "ÜSE ISO_C_BINDING" near the top)

Comment: The book "Numerical Recipes in Fortran 90" covers many prominent statistical and mathematical routines: www.elch.chem.msu.ru/tch/group/FortranBooks/NumericalRecipesinF90.pdf